# Book with angels as crows and anger as plant

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book between 2000 and 2005 in the public library. It was in German language. I could not remember the picture or the title. I have a very far association with a hard cover.

The main character was a young adult, maybe a little younger. I do not remember if a boy or girl. If I remember this I have the picture of an angry and sad person in mind.

Through some circumstances, maybe nearly death, this person explores/could see that angels act as crows in our world. They help people with their power and all the humans see are crows. This is the reason why so many crows are near highways and other daily dangerous places.

In the later story a plant tries to destroy the person. The plant grows out of the persons heart with thorns and I think it had a pale color. I associated it with fear, anger and sadness, which would destroy the loving heart. One plant related story part took place at a grave yard.

It may be, that the person comes into a dark room, maybe basement at this grave yard, find the plant and eat some part of it.

I could not remember a special area where the story is taking place, but it was in the present "normal" world.

I would like to read it again, does anybody know this book?

Comment: This makes me think of Patricia McKillip; have you read any of her books?

Comment: @DavidW I have scrolled through the wikipedia bibliography but now title sounds familiar (only in english). all titles seem to be in an middleage fantastic context. The book I search for takes place in present. Maxbe you have one special in mind?

Answer (score 6):

*[Tell Me What You See](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1319412.Tell_Me_What_You_See)* by Zoran Drvenkar. I was looking up this book too again and found it and saw you were never answered.

> Berlin, Christmas, the dead of night: 16-year-old Alissa and her best friend, Evelin, are making their annual secret pilgrimage to the grave of Alissa's father when Alissa falls through thick snow to land in an underground crypt. There she finds a child's casket...with a strange black plant growing up through its lid. Opening the coffin, she severs the dark growth from its roots--and discovers they are embedded in the heart of the dead child.
>
> From that moment forward, Alissa's life descends into nightmarish turmoil.

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1232492860?book_show_action=true) mentions the crows as angels obliquely:

> .... Around midnight Alissa is home and asleep. Then she is woken up by to creatures entering her room. They are surprised that she can see them and they are looking for the plant. They leave before Alissa can get answers. Alissa starts seeing things other people cant see. Such as all the crows can turn into people and they come when a child calls out for help. ....

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice find! Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the description given in the question though?

Comment: Edited in Goodreads summary.